# Points In Attribute Table Will Not Display In Data View

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, display

I am using ArcMap 10.2.2 and opening a shapefile of points. My issues is this: the points do not appear in the data view. In other words, I cannot view the points in the display where they usually appear. I opened the attribute table and there are indeed several hundred points listed there; they just don't appear in the data view as they normally would. I have also tried "zooming to layer" just to be sure that I'm not off in la la land while the data is sitting somewhere else. This is does not help either.

***NOTE: I was given this shapefile from another source, and it did not come with a spatial reference. Hence, when I add this shapefile to the Table of Contents, it alerts me to the fact that there is no spatial reference. Perhaps this has something to do with it?

Also, the person who gave me this shapefile only provided me with a .shp, .shx and .dbf. Perhaps this has something to do with it as well...

Comment: are there any coordinates in the attribute tables to give a clue as to the projection?

Comment: Try to remove *.sb* files, i.e. *.sbn and *.sbx

Comment: If you add the layer to a new, blank document and then zoom to layer, they still don't show up? Is there anything in the ToC for a symbol? If not, you may have a corrupted file. The files you were given are the core mandatory files and are all that is *technically* needed - obviously they won't have the correct spatial reference since there's no prj, but if metadata or you were told what the reference is you could assign it. But if it's corrupt, a [geometry validation tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005600000010000000) may be your only choice.

Comment: @ChrisW - +1 for your idea of bringing the shapefile into a blank ArcMap document.  Often when there is some spatial reference conflict, you can have a perfectly valid spatial layer, regardless of format, but it will not show up when brought in to a data frame containing other layers which all have defined spatial references.  If you have no luck in ArcMap, you might try opening it in QGIS, which can be more forgiving of quirks in shapefiles than is ArcMap.